# How to capture and send images from raspberry pi, which is in field to a website hosted with word press

Tags: camera, raspicam

I have a website (hosted by word press) and i need to capture and receive images form raspberry pi from the field to the website.
is this possible?

any valuable info will be taken

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should be possible.

**1. Image uploading via FTP**

One way is to upload images from your RPi to your WP site's images (or such) directory via (S)FTP.
 For this, you have to have (S)FTP access enabled on your website.
Then RPi would be the (S)FTP client, and your webserver the (S)FTP server.
Definitely go with SFTP if your webserver supports that, plain FTP is treated unsecure.

Try `sftp` from RPi command prompt for client options (should be available by default on raspbian-wheezy).

**2. Image uploading via HTTP**

In case you cannot/don't want (S)FTP, use a HTTP image uploader.

Your site needs to have an image upload page, to which a script (running on your RPi) can automatically log on in the background, and submit the image file(S) as a HTTP request.

Login example:
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189555/how-to-use-python-to-login-to-a-webpage-and-retrieve-cookies-for-later-usage

File upload example:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68477/send-file-using-post-from-a-python-script

**3. Displaying images on WP site**

You should install a gallery or an image-displaying plugin depending on your wish.